# onkeyup event does not work

Tags: javascript

`onkeypress` it's work good but Why `onkeyup` not working ? How to do for working with `onkeyup` ?

https://jsfiddle.net/btykt0nk/

```js
function isNumber(number_check) {
    number_check = (number_check) ? number_check : window.event;
    var charCode = (number_check.which) ? number_check.which : number_check.keyCode;
    console.log(charCode);
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="return isNumber(event);">
```

Comment: remove ```return```: ```onkeyup="isNumber(event)"```

Comment: flagged since issue can't be reproduced. This code works pretty fine. Also add the code here itself from next time onwards, Make use of StackSnippets

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use `return` here, you just need to attach your function to the `onkeyup` event:

```
onkeyup="isNumber(event)"
```

```js
function isNumber(event) {
  event = (event) ? event : window.event;
  var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
  //console.log(charCode);
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
     console.log(false);
  }else{
     console.log(true);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="return isNumber(event);">
```

And in your function use `console.log(true)` and `console.log(false)` to track the result, because `return false` or `return true`won't be very helpful here.

**EDIT:**

To make your input accept only numbers you can use `event.preventDeafult()`  along with `onkeypress` event because `onkeyup` will fire the function after writing that character, it will exit when it isn't a number:

```js
function isNumber(event) {
  event = (event) ? event : window.event;
  var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
  //console.log(charCode);
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
     console.log(false);
     event.preventDefault();
  }else{
     console.log(true);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeypress="isNumber(event);">
```

Comment: StackSnippet is here and then why you ask for fiddle @poretuterdi

Comment: sorry please give me some StackSnippet ^_^

Comment: check the question. I added the code from fiddle to your question as a snippet and added a `console.log` it works pretty fine without any issue.

Comment: I want to allow number only ? how can i do ?

Comment: @poretuterdi In that case you need to edit your code to prevent updating value when it isn't a number (and you should included that in your question in first place), I am editing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

We should handle it in onkeypress.

Check this out

```
<input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'>
</input>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try onkeyup="isNumber(event)" (without return)
Updated your fiddle 
`<input type="text" onkeyup="isNumber(event)">`
https://jsfiddle.net/btykt0nk/1/

Comment: not work , When i fill char eg: a-z , it's display in input. i allow only number.

Comment: Your question is just about the onkeyup not working isn't it ?